# Gunicorn + django сильно грузит процессор

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

При запуске в режиме DEBUG=True через gunicorn нагрузка на процессор около 30-40%.
При точно таком же запуске в DEBUG=False нагрузка выростает до 80%.

На картинке перезапуск из режима дебага в боевой [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ранее приложение работало на:

1. python 2.7
2. django 1.8
3. mysql 5.7
4. у gunicorn 16 воркеров
5. nginx
6. все запускалось локально

Переход на новую версию:

1. python 3.11
2. django 4.0
3. mysql 8.0
4. у gunicorn 16 воркеров
5. кроме nginx, все в докере.

Старая версия в боевом режиме грузила процессор так же как новая в режиме отладки.

Пытался:

1. проверить код на наличие доп фичей, запускаемых в боевом режиме.
2. логировал запросы к бд на предмет особо длительных (среднее 0.015 c, макс 0.03 с).
3. прогнал через debug-toolbar - не нашел отличий при работе в этих режимах.
4. Эксперементировал с количеством воркеров и их типом.

Как режим дебага может влиять на загрузку процессора при запуске через гуникорн?

Comment: Профилировщик в руки и вперёд искать что конкретно тормозит

Comment: А влияние DEBUG'а намекает, что, может быть, вы сами опираетесь на этот DEBUG где-то в коде

Comment: Вопрос почему гуникорн может нагружать так процессор, хотя по логике nginx снимает с него часть нагрузки?

Comment: может быть подскажете какой то конкретный? я пробовал debug-toolbar, но как то не нашел там нужной информации. И код я перелопатил на предмет вовлеченности DEBUG

Comment: Да вот хоть третья ссылка из гугла https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk

Comment: А лично мне всегда хватало и тупого `print(time.time() - start_time)` без всяких навороченных профилировщиков

Comment: приложение не стало работать медленнее при смене режима, но нагрузка на процессор выросла, поэтому я даже не аытался отследить время выполнения функций.